# how to strsplit and keep other variables in the new df

Tags: r, dataframe, strsplit

Sorry for such silly question. I have a df that looks like this:

[image]

I want to split tx with `data.frame(do.call("rbind", strsplit(as.character(df$tx),  "\\s{2,}" )), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`  , how can I keep `Form` in the new df? Also, how can i avoid the split results auto fill if it is empty?

sample df can be build using:

```
df<- structure(list(tx = c(" [1]          Timepoint                                       EGTMPT      Categorical select one (nominal) 51         Screening", 
" [2]          N/A : O ff-Study                                EGTNA       Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3", 
" [3]          Check if Not Done                               EGTMPTND    Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3", 
" [4]          Date Performed                                  ECGDT       Date                             11", 
" [5]          Time (24-hour format)                           ECGTM       Time                             5", 
" [6]          O verall ECG Interpretation                     ECGRES      Categorical select one (nominal) 37         Normal"
), Form = c("12-Lead Electrocardiogram (EG) at Log Pages (Dosing, ECG, PBMC, Biomarkers, PK)", 
"12-Lead Electrocardiogram (EG) at Log Pages (Dosing, ECG, PBMC, Biomarkers, PK)", 
"12-Lead Electrocardiogram (EG) at Log Pages (Dosing, ECG, PBMC, Biomarkers, PK)", 
"12-Lead Electrocardiogram (EG) at Log Pages (Dosing, ECG, PBMC, Biomarkers, PK)", 
"12-Lead Electrocardiogram (EG) at Log Pages (Dosing, ECG, PBMC, Biomarkers, PK)", 
"12-Lead Electrocardiogram (EG) at Log Pages (Dosing, ECG, PBMC, Biomarkers, PK)"
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

the output will looks like this:
[image]

Update:
How should I separate tx in a better way. My old codes seems generate errors. The sample data is:

```
df<-structure(list(tx = c("[6]          O verall ECG Interpretation                     ECGRES      Categorical select one (nominal) 37         Normal", 
"[7]          If A bnormal - Clinically Significant, describe ECGA BN     Text or A ny V alue              200", 
"[8]          PR Interval (ms)                                ECGPRIN     Number (continuous)              15", 
"[1]          Not Done                            PE2ND       Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3", 
"[2]          If Not Done, specify reason:        PE2NDR      Text or A ny V alue              200", 
"[4]          Start Date:                                  A ESTDTC    Date                             11", 
"[5]          End Date                                     A EENDTC    Date                             11", 
"[6]          O ngoing:                                    A EO NGO    Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3", 
"[7]          Seriousness Criteria: (check all that apply) A ESA E     Categorical select multiple      50", 
"[8]          Severity:                                    A ECTCA E   Categorical select one (nominal) 26         Grade 1 - Mild", 
"[2]          If Not Done, specify reason:                    CHMNO       Text or A ny V alue              200", 
"[6]          Laboratory ID (NO TE: If Lab ID is not present, CHMID       Categorical select one (nominal) 71         Christus Mother Frances Hospital Laboratory", 
"[1]          Has subject had any prior surgery related to the PSYN        Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3", 
"[2]          Cycle 1 O nly: If less than the expected number of EXBC1       Categorical select one (nominal) 3", 
"[3]          Cycle                                              EXBCYC      Categorical select one (nominal) 8          Cycle 1", 
"[4]          Dose (mg)                                          EXBDO S     Number (continuous)              15", 
"[5]          Frequency                                          EXBFRQ      Categorical select one (nominal) 3          BID", 
"[6]          Start Date                                         EXBSTDT     Date                             11", 
"[7]          Stop Date                                          EXBENDT     Date                             11", 
"[8]          Reason for End Date/Stopping                       EXBREA      Categorical select one (nominal) 36         Cycle Completed", 
"[9]          O ther Reason (specify)                            EXBREA S    Text or A ny V alue              200"
)), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

the output I had is:

[image]

the yellow part should be in x3 instead. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `splitstackshape::cSplit` :

```
splitstackshape::cSplit(df, 'tx', sep = '\\s{2,}', fixed = FALSE)

#                                                                              Form tx_1
#1: 12-Lead Electrocardiogram (EG) at Log Pages (Dosing, ECG, PBMC, Biomarkers, PK)  [1]
#2: 12-Lead Electrocardiogram (EG) at Log Pages (Dosing, ECG, PBMC, Biomarkers, PK)  [2]
#3: 12-Lead Electrocardiogram (EG) at Log Pages (Dosing, ECG, PBMC, Biomarkers, PK)  [3]
#4: 12-Lead Electrocardiogram (EG) at Log Pages (Dosing, ECG, PBMC, Biomarkers, PK)  [4]
#5: 12-Lead Electrocardiogram (EG) at Log Pages (Dosing, ECG, PBMC, Biomarkers, PK)  [5]
#6: 12-Lead Electrocardiogram (EG) at Log Pages (Dosing, ECG, PBMC, Biomarkers, PK)  [6]

#                          tx_2     tx_3                                   tx_4      tx_5
#1:                   Timepoint   EGTMPT Categoricals{2,}elect one (nominal) 51 Screening
#2:            N/A : O ff-Study    EGTNA     Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3      <NA>
#3:           Check if Not Done EGTMPTND     Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3      <NA>
#4:              Date Performed    ECGDT                                   Date        11
#5:       Time (24-hour format)    ECGTM                                   Time         5
#6: O verall ECG Interpretation   ECGRES Categoricals{2,}elect one (nominal) 37    Normal
```

With `tidyr::separate` :

```
tidyr::separate(df, 'tx', paste0('col', 1:5), sep = '\\s{2,}', fill = 'right')
```

Comment: Any other way to do the same thing? Try to limit the package used during the process. Many thanks

Comment: Do you want to do this only in base R ?

Comment: thinking of (tidyverse/dplyr) or base R

Comment: Updated the answer to use `tidyr::separate`.

Comment: Many thanks. Those are wonderful. I also have a question on separate part. Please see updated data.

Comment: I don't get any error on the new `df`. what is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: Added the output. The yellow part is the problem.

Comment: Yes, so this relies on the fact that you have whitespace of 2 or more characters between each column. Since the incorrect (yellow part) does not have whitespace of 2 or more characters it does not split there. If you have data like this you need to define clearly what goes in 1st column, what goes in 2nd column etc since just splitting by whitespace will not work.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on how to better separate it?

Comment: I don't have complete data so can't really make a suggestion because I am sure there would be many more edge cases in your actual data than the ones shown. But after looking at complete data try to come up with rules which will clearly define column contents. For example, column 1 has a number between `[]`, column 2 is everything after that until 1 or 2 uppercase letter etc like this for all 5 columns.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `read.csv()` after cleaning with `gsub`.

The inner `gsub` gives the numeric column on the right more space, and the outer transforms white space into a comma which is default `sep=','` in `read.csv()`.

```
dat_clean <- cbind(read.csv(text=gsub('\\s{2,}', ',', gsub('\\s+(\\d+)', '  \\1', trimws(df$tx))),
                            header=F, na.strings=''), Form=df$Form)
dat_clean
# V1                          V2       V3                               V4 V5        V6
# 1 [1]                   Timepoint   EGTMPT Categorical select one (nominal) 51 Screening
# 2 [2]            N/A : O ff-Study    EGTNA Categorical yes/no (dichotomous)  3      <NA>
# 3 [3]           Check if Not Done EGTMPTND Categorical yes/no (dichotomous)  3      <NA>
# 4 [4]              Date Performed    ECGDT                             Date 11      <NA>
# 5 [5]       Time (24-hour format)    ECGTM                             Time  5      <NA>
# 6 [6] O verall ECG Interpretation   ECGRES Categorical select one (nominal) 37    Normal
# Form
# 1 12-Lead Electrocardiogram (EG) at Log Pages (Dosing, ECG, PBMC, Biomarkers, PK)
# 2 12-Lead Electrocardiogram (EG) at Log Pages (Dosing, ECG, PBMC, Biomarkers, PK)
# 3 12-Lead Electrocardiogram (EG) at Log Pages (Dosing, ECG, PBMC, Biomarkers, PK)
# 4 12-Lead Electrocardiogram (EG) at Log Pages (Dosing, ECG, PBMC, Biomarkers, PK)
# 5 12-Lead Electrocardiogram (EG) at Log Pages (Dosing, ECG, PBMC, Biomarkers, PK)
# 6 12-Lead Electrocardiogram (EG) at Log Pages (Dosing, ECG, PBMC, Biomarkers, PK)
```

Better would be if we could use `read.fwf()` but it seems to read only from a file.

Note that if in your data there are missings in the columns to the left, you probably need to adapt the code a little.